# Flutter: Modifying a state modifies other states using setState in TextField

Tags: flutter, dart

When i modify agentName state and switch to the next screen, i see agentName value in clientName.
How do i modify just the agentName state and after the screen switch i modify just the clientName?

```dart
Screens(
  index: index,
  children: [
    Screen(
        child: Column(
        children: [
          Field(
          onChanged: (String value) => setState(() => agentName = value)
          ),
          ScreenButtons(
            previous: () => setState(() => index--), 
            next: () => setState(() => index++), 
            index: index, 
            length: 2
          )
        ]
      )
    ),
    Screen(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Field(
            onChanged: (String value) => setState(() => clientName = value),
          ),
          ScreenButtons(
            previous: () => setState(() => index--), 
            next: () => setState(() => index++), 
            index: index, 
            length: 2
          )
        ]
      )
    )
  ]
);
```

Comment: Could you please share the actual widgets that you use? Also what kind of state management do you have? Do these screen widgets share the same state, because agentName does not have a state on it's own, but the widget that contains it has a state.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved it using IndexedStack widget.

Comment: Share code of how you solved it, and mark your solution as accepted. This will help future persons with the same problem

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).